# How to get RSS feeds updates on my android application without sending requests to the server continuously

Tags: android

**is it possible  to get any update in feeds without the need of sending requests to the server contiguously ?!. is there a way like windows phone to let my application listen to the web server (channel) ? so if there were updates the web server will send the new feeds without the need of any request from the android application.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally write a server side component for this. The server polls the RSS feed regularly, often triggered by a cron job or the like. Clients register for push messages with the server. The server sends them push messages on update. See GCM for Android's implementation of push:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html